# Matlab: repeat string using repmat and concatenating the output with a cell

Tags: matlab

Basically, I am trying to repeat 2 strings 3 times by doing `test1=repmat({'aaaa'},1,3)` and `test2=repmat({'bbbb'},1,3)`. And then I want to put them into another cell called `final` such that I will get an output like this:

`final = {'aaaa' 'aaaa' 'aaaa' 'cccc' 'bbbb' 'bbbb' 'bbbb'}`

But it failed and instead this is what I got in my output:
`final={ {1x3 cell} 'cccc' {1x3 cell} }`

I tried searching for answers by looking at different posts here but I did not find anything useful. This is why I created this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following variables:

```
test1=repmat({'aaaa'},1,3);
test2 = 'cccc';
test3=repmat({'bbbb'},1,3);
```

then `test1` and `test3` will be `1x3` cell arrays, while `test2` is simply a string or char array.
If you would now use

```
final = {test1, test2, test3};
```

then `final` would become a `1x3` cell, where the first element is again a `1x3` cell (`test1`), the second element is a string (`test2`) and the third element is again a `1x3` cell. This is what you described in your question.

If instead you use

```
final = {test1{:}, test2, test3{:}}
```

the contents of `test1` and `test2` are inserted, not the cell itself. (See the [MATLAB help pages](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) for details on accessing data in cell arrays). The output will thus be a `1x7` cell array containing: first the content (i.e. 3 strings) of `test1`, then `test2`, and last the content of `test3`.
The result will be

```
final = 
    'aaaa'    'aaaa'    'aaaa'    'cccc'    'bbbb'    'bbbb'    'bbbb'
```